# Stack Overflow Talent blurb mentions Stack Exchange but links to Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-talent

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/talent/en and scroll down to the blurb "100 Million+ visitors a month to Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange". The link behind "Stack Exchange" points to https://stackoverflow.com/ instead of to https://stackexchange.com/

[image]

The actual code looks like:

```
<div class="flex--item9 fc-black-700 fs-body3">
    <strong class="p-ff-source-bold">Million+</strong> visitors a month to
    <a href="/">Stack Overflow</a>
    and<br class="sm:d-none">
    <a href="/">Stack Exchange</a>
    <div class="fs-caption pt6 fc-black-200">Source: Comscore</div>
</div>
```

So the second `href="/"` shouldn't be a relative link.

Comment: Thanks for reporting, we'll get that updated and report back